# How to tell the object of the death of another object?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

On my work I have met with one bug which can be described as follows.
There are two classes, class A and class B:

```
class A
{
public:
    void print(){}
};  

class B
{
    A* a;
public:
    void init(A* _a) {
        a = _a;
    }
    void PrintWithA()
    {
        a->print();
    }
};

A* a;
B* b;
b->init(a);

// some code .....
delete a;        // line 1
a = NULL;
// some code .....

b->PrintWithA(); // line 2
```

Object "b" doesn't know nothing about state of object "a".  In line 1 "a"object has been deleted but on line 2 we continue to use it. When there are a lot of code it is very easy to make such mistake. 
My question is the following - which approch to use to avoid some mistakes? I guess I could use observer pattern - but I think it is unjustifiably expensive solution.
Thank's.

Comment: What's the behaviour you want? Disallowing the deletion of `a` if it's currently in use? Also destroying `b` because it is in an invalid state? But you should probably look into smart pointers, it looks like `b` owns `a`, and thus should have the ownership (`unique_ptr`) or at least share it (`shared_ptr`).

Comment: Whatever you do, get rid of pointers. Than think about ownership and you might use st:::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr and std weak_ptr. (You might even avoid these)

Comment: At first the object "b" stays valid after deleting of the "a". My exampleis short part of code in order to explain the problem. Also consider situation where instead of one object I have array of "b" objects. And every has pointer on "a". What I realy want - don't call PrintWithA() method if object "a"is not valid.

Comment: In it's current state the question is ridiculously broad, and feels like a http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: C++ does not have a global mechanism for notifying on free.  You can get close with `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`, as mentioned earlier.  Otherwise you'll need a bunch of custom plumbing with event registrations and notify-on-destroy in destructors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a weak ptr (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

basically you can provide class B with a weak ptr of A.

whenever comes time to access A, you can try to lock the weak ptr to see if it's still valid.

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    void print(){}
};  

class B
{
    std::weak_ptr<A> a;
public:
    void init(std::weak_ptr<A> _a) {
        a = _a;
    }
    void PrintWithA()
    {
        if (auto spt = a.lock()) { 
            spt->print();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    std::unique_ptr<B> b = std::make_unique<B>();
    b->init(a);

    // some code .....
    a = nullptr;
    // some code .....

    b->PrintWithA(); // line 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good solution. But I will slightly change my example - really It is closer to what I encountered. Let we have vector<A*> , "b" object has pointer on some element of this vector. In some moment this element can be erased from vector. How can I tell about it to "b"object. I want to call PrintWithA() method only for valid evements of this vector.

Comment: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> and give some std::weak_ptr to B. you will be able to use the same code.

Otherwise you'll need to create some kind of notification system within B's destructor so that it notifies A that B is not longer valid

Answer (score 0):

To guard against that, either B needs to take ownership of the lifetime of A when the object B is constructed, or you need to make A reference counted.

C++11 I think has the concept of a shared pointer which maintains the references and will prevent the object A from being deleted if someone has a reference.  See `std::shared_ptr`

If you are not using C++11 there is `boost::shared_ptr` which does essentially the same thing.  But you need the boost library which I personally prefer not to use, but it's up to you.

Use them like this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr;

A_ptr a = new A();

class B
{
    A_ptr a;
public:
    void B(A_ptr _a) {
        a = _a;
    }
    void PrintWithA()
    {
        a->print();
    }
};
```

Otherwise you could put something together yourself.  Something along the lines of:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){
      ref_count = 1;
    }

    void print(){}

    void grab() {
      ref_count++;
    }

    void release() {
      ref_count--;
      if (ref_count <= 0)
        ~A();
    }
private:
    int ref_count;

    ~A(){
      delete this;
    }
};
```

Inside B you'd assign the pointer and call grab();

Rather than call delete (which wouldn't work because it's private) you'd call
a->release() on the pointer.

Now this is not particularly fantastic because you can't use this form:

```
A a;
```

So it's not ideal.  But if you're using some compiler that doesn't have a shared_ptr and you don't mind the limitation you may use this or a form of it.  In general, use **shared_ptr**.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the line that says `A* a;` should probably be `A* a = new A;`.

In c++ you need to encode this awareness explicitly, it's not done automatically.

One thing you can do is check if `_a` is NULL inside `PrintWithA`, but this won't work if you make sure that you always set your pointers to NULL after `delete[]`ing them (which you've done)

Comment: Doesn't help : b->a will not NULL even if I make a = NULL.